# Symfony2: ondelete cascade for inverse relations

Tags: php, symfony

I have an address entity, which is used in various other entities, there are users with an address, there are shops and companies.

Now what I try to do is make sure an address is automatically deleted when a shop is deleted, so I tried this:

```
/**
 * Shop
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Shop {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $address;

    ...
}

/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address {
    //... 
}
```

But this does not do what I want, after deleting a shop the address is still there. How can I handle this, is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the cascade `remove` option

```
/**
 * Shop
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Shop {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist, remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $address;

    ...
}
```

`onDelete="CASCADE"` means that when the embedded entity is deleted, the parent entity must be deleted too. It's handled at database level.

`cascade={"remove"}` means that on parent deletion, the embedded entity must be deleted. It's handled at orm level.

Note that you don't need to specify `nullable=true` in the JoinColumn annotation, true is the default value.

**Update after comments**

If your entities only have one address, then you should use a OneToOne relation. If you want to have a reference back to Shop in Address then you want a bidirectional one, else you'll have an unidirectional one.

Unidirectional:

```
/**
 * Shop
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Shop {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist, remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $address;

    // ...
}

/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address {
    // ...
}
```

Bidirectional:

```
/**
 * Shop
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Shop {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="shop", cascade={"persist, remove"})
     */
    private $address;

    // ...
}

/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Shop", inversedBy="address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $shop;

    // Same for user / company
    // ...
}
```

Comment: when I tried it with cascade={"persist","remove"} it doesn't work - when I delete a shop the address is still there

Comment: @Chi You need to specify the owning side of the association, add the `mappedBy="shop"` option to the ManyToOne annotation (be sure the attribute's name is shop in your Address entity, or give the right one).

Comment: but that doesn't make sense in this case because address doesn't always have a club, giving it multiple columns for shop, user, company, etc. seems strange to me

Comment: @Chi can you update your question with the Address entity pls?

Comment: the address entity has no reference to shop / user / company. It just has some varchar fiels like street, city, etc.

Comment: you need a reference to the other entities (like shop, user etc.) otherwise cascade cannot work in this direction.

Comment: @Chi some questions to understand better: 1) can a shop have more than one address? 2) can two shops have the same address? 3) can a shop and a user have the same address?

Comment: a shop / user / company all have only 1 address and neither can have the same address

Comment: thank you! should the cascade = remove work in the unidirectionaly way too ?

Comment: @Chi yes it should

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work. I'll update my current entities, but I see no difference to your unidirectional approach. yet when a shop is deleted, the address remains

Comment: @Chi Try adding `orphanRemoval=true` in the OneToOne annotation in the Shop entity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125007/discussion-between-lolmx-and-chi).